# Running FitNesse Tests with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, fitnesse

So, I found this plugin for TeamCity that is supposed to run FitNesse tests https://github.com/EKibort/TeamCityFitnessePlugin

I'm struggling with getting it installed.  The instructions in the readme says,

**Installation copy `Fitnesse.zip` to plugins directory (for windows `%USERPROFILE%\.BuildServer\plugins`) and resart TeamCity server**

There is no `Fitnesse.zip`. Any advice on how to get this installed?

**2nd question**:  Is this the best way to go about running FitNess tests from TeamCity?  Any alternate option advice is welcomed.

Comment: The author now includes the built *FitNesse.zip* file in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the plugin first. Have you read the readme?

Comment: Yes.  Got the package built and dropped into %USER_HOME%\.BuildServer and restarted everything...no FitNesse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out I was putting the built plugin in the wrong place.  I was following the directions and putting in place on the BUILD AGENT machine, not the BUILD SERVER machine.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.